# tGeneral purpose ticketing/tech support system

Tags: untagged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s your favorite ticketing system?](https://serverfault.com/questions/43072/whats-your-favorite-ticketing-system)

I was wondering if somebody could recommend me a very user friendly or simple general purpose ticketing/tech support system. I need something that is web based, preferably open-sourced/free software implemented using PHP, Ruby, Ruby on Rails or Java (as back end) with MySQL or PostgreSQL as database engine.

I need something that is not development management oriented or project management oriented like Eventum or similar (random example), something to which the user can connect open a tech support request and be able to follow it until is solved or dropped.I need it to be open-sourced to be able to modify it if there is a need or extend it.

I tried a number of such systems available and I found that osTicket or eTicket is something that it's close to what I need, but the code is somewhat flaky and some of the features are working badly or behaving strangely. Any thoughts/advice where to find something similar? Thanks!

Comment: Also see: http://serverfault.com/questions/89761/

Answer (score 6):

Well, I've used Request Tracker (RT) in the past with good success.  It's written in perl and uses mysql for the backend.  Some of the configuration can be a bit difficult to figure out but once you have it running it is very reliable.

I particularly like the email ticket submission mechanism in RT.  You can tell users to just email their requests to a special address and RT very transparently handles turning that into a ticket.

Comment: +1 For adding that extra meat I forgot to add.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at the following two ServerFault threads for some inspiration:
[What's your favorite ticketing system?](https://serverfault.com/questions/43072/whats-your-favorite-ticketing-system)
[Good free Helpdesk software?](https://serverfault.com/questions/89761/good-free-helpdesk-software)

As well as looking at the following site (since open-source is a priority for you):
http://www.opensourcehelpdesklist.com/

Those links should at least give you the good base of products to explore further. I'm sure at least ***one*** of them has to be simple and user friendly. =)

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest and nicest that I used in the past is: [The Bug Genie](http://www.thebuggenie.com) I found it very cool.

(I use Redmine today as it's more geared towards development, and also used Trac in the past.)

Hope it helps,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Might [RT](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) be what you are looking for?

(Well, written i Perl, but otherwise it might fit your request.)

Answer (score 1):

We looked at RT but decided it did more than we required for a help desk system so we installed [OS Ticket](http://osticket.com/) and it seems to do everything we need.

Peter.

Answer (score 0):

[Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) is NOT open source, but works very well. It runs on Windows using Mongrel ball user requests and handling of tickets is through your browser. It's free because it is ad-supported, but if that bothers you, install Ad-Block Plus for Firefox and block away.